# Dropbox sign (fka Hellosign) sharing templates with the team

Tags: dropbox-sign

We’ve got a paid Dropbox (storage) plan, advanced level. This gives us access to Dropbox Sign (was Hellosign) for the whole team.

I’ve created a template for our sales contract that I want the whole team to be able to use.

Their [instructions](https://faq.hellosign.com/hc/en-us/articles/210562998) say I can share the template with the team by clicking the ellipsis and hitting *Share* in the templates screen. Spoiler: the Share option is missing from this menu (circled).

[image: Dropbox Sign Borked]

Dropbox support don’t know and auto closed my support ticket today.

Has anyone gotten shared templates to work in Dropbox Sign/Hellosign? How did you do it?